# java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, websocket, atmosphere

I am using the wAsync library, Websocket protocol and Atmosphere to send request, by following this article:
https://github.com/Atmosphere/wasync/wiki/Getting-Started-with-wAsync

Here is what I have implemented:

```
    try
    {
        AtmosphereClient client = ClientFactory.getDefault().newClient(AtmosphereClient.class);
        RequestBuilder<?> requestBuilder =
            client.newRequestBuilder()
                .method(Request.METHOD.GET)
                .uri(url)
                .trackMessageLength(false)
                .transport(Request.TRANSPORT.WEBSOCKET)        // Try Websocket.
                .transport(Request.TRANSPORT.LONG_POLLING);    // Fall back to Long pooling.

        final Socket socket = client.create();
        socket.open(requestBuilder.build()).fire(pMessage);
        socket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
```

The `socket.fire` works successfully.

But sometimes I receive the following error:

```
15:11:36,467 ERROR [org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-79) : java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.write0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.access$900(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$WriteTask.run(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:777) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implWrite(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:914) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.write(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:381) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.write(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:398) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:978) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$1.completed(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$1.completed(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:200) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$DefaultThreadFactory$1$1.run(NioEndpoint.java:1249) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]

15:11:36,469 ERROR [org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-79) : java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.write0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.access$900(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl$WriteTask.run(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:777) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implWrite(WindowsAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:914) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.write(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:381) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.write(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:398) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:978) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$1.completed(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioOutputBuffer$1.completed(InternalNioOutputBuffer.java:200) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$DefaultThreadFactory$1$1.run(NioEndpoint.java:1249) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_76]
```

This error can't be caught by try-catch block.

If I remove `socket.close()`, this error never occurs.

Anybody knows why? How should I solve this? Or is there a way to catch this exception?

Thanks in advance!

***************** **UPDATE** **********************

The socket needs to be closed.

Is there a callback method that I can invoke when the fire operation completes?

Comment: So don’t call `close()` before the operation has been completed.

Comment: Hi Holger, how can I know when the operation is completed? There is no callback for this.

Comment: How about using the `Future` returned by `fire(…)`?

Comment: I tried to use future.get() to wait until the computation is done, but the error still occurs from time to time